# how to validate decimal numbers in PHP

Tags: php, validation

how to validate decimal numbers in PHP.  I looked at is_numeric() but that won't work for me:

> bool is_numeric ( mixed var )
>
> Finds whether the given variable is
>   numeric. Numeric strings consist of
>   optional sign, any number of digits,
>   optional decimal part **and optional
>   exponential part**. Thus +0123.45e6 is a
>   valid numeric value. **Hexadecimal
>   notation (0xFF) is allowed too** but
>   only without sign, decimal and
>   exponential part.

**I don't want the exponent part or hexadecimal notation.**  The user will be entering in simple decimal values and I don't want a type-o that just happens to be a valid exponent or hex value to slip past.  I'd just like "traditional" decimal numbers to be consdered valid.

**EDIT** here a simple (brute force) page that contains much more complete test data (what should and should not be considered a numeric value).

```
<html><head></head>
<body>

<?php

function TestFunction($s_value) {
    //
    //  your code here
    //
    return; //true or false;
}

print '<b>these are valid numbers and should return "true"</b><br>';
print '<pre>';
    $s_value='123';     print "\n".'$s_value="'.$s_value.'", TestFunction()='.(TestFunction($s_value)?'true':'false');
    $s_value='+1';      print "\n".'$s_value="'.$s_value.'", TestFunction()='.(TestFunction($s_value)?'true':'false');
    $s_value='-1';      print "\n".'$s_value="'.$s_value.'", TestFunction()='.(TestFunction($s_value)?'true':'false');
    $s_value='  1';     print "\n".'$s_value="'.$s_value.'", TestFunction()='.(TestFunction($s_value)?'true':'false');
    $s_value='1  ';     print "\n".'$s_value="'.$s_value.'", TestFunction()='.(TestFunction($s_value)?'true':'false');
    $s_value='  1  ';   print "\n".'$s_value="'.$s_value.'", TestFunction()='.(TestFunction($s_value)?'true':'false');
    $s_value='1';       print "\n".'$s_value="'.$s_value.'", TestFunction()='.(TestFunction($s_value)?'true':'false');
    $s_value='12345.1'; print "\n".'$s_value="'.$s_value.'", TestFunction()='.(TestFunction($s_value)?'true':'false');
    $s_value='6789.01'; print "\n".'$s_value="'.$s_value.'", TestFunction()='.(TestFunction($s_value)?'true':'false');
    $s_value='-1.1';    print "\n".'$s_value="'.$s_value.'", TestFunction()='.(TestFunction($s_value)?'true':'false');
    $s_value='+1.1';    print "\n".'$s_value="'.$s_value.'", TestFunction()='.(TestFunction($s_value)?'true':'false');
    $s_value='0';       print "\n".'$s_value="'.$s_value.'", TestFunction()='.(TestFunction($s_value)?'true':'false');
    $s_value='00001.1'; print "\n".'$s_value="'.$s_value.'", TestFunction()='.(TestFunction($s_value)?'true':'false');
    $s_value='.1';      print "\n".'$s_value="'.$s_value.'", TestFunction()='.(TestFunction($s_value)?'true':'false');
    $s_value='.0000001';print "\n".'$s_value="'.$s_value.'", TestFunction()='.(TestFunction($s_value)?'true':'false');
    $s_value='5.';      print "\n".'$s_value="'.$s_value.'", TestFunction()='.(TestFunction($s_value)?'true':'false');
print '</pre>';

print '<br><b>these are NOT valid numbers and should return "false"</b><br>';
print '<pre>';

    $s_value='--------------------------------';print "\n".'$s_value="'.$s_value.'", TestFunction()='.(TestFunction($s_value)?'true':'false');
    $s_value=null;      print "\n".'$s_value=null, TestFunction()='.(TestFunction($s_value)?'true':'false');
    $s_value='.';       print "\n".'$s_value="'.$s_value.'", TestFunction()='.(TestFunction($s_value)?'true':'false');
    $s_value='';        print "\n".'$s_value="'.$s_value.'", TestFunction()='.(TestFunction($s_value)?'true':'false');
    $s_value=' ';       print "\n".'$s_value="'.$s_value.'", TestFunction()='.(TestFunction($s_value)?'true':'false');
    $s_value='  ';      print "\n".'$s_value="'.$s_value.'", TestFunction()='.(TestFunction($s_value)?'true':'false');
    $s_value='1abc';    print "\n".'$s_value="'.$s_value.'", TestFunction()='.(TestFunction($s_value)?'true':'false');
    $s_value='$1';      print "\n".'$s_value="'.$s_value.'", TestFunction()='.(TestFunction($s_value)?'true':'false');
    $s_value='1@';      print "\n".'$s_value="'.$s_value.'", TestFunction()='.(TestFunction($s_value)?'true':'false');
    $s_value='1.2.1';   print "\n".'$s_value="'.$s_value.'", TestFunction()='.(TestFunction($s_value)?'true':'false');
    $s_value='abc';     print "\n".'$s_value="'.$s_value.'", TestFunction()='.(TestFunction($s_value)?'true':'false');
    $s_value='1.45e6';  print "\n".'$s_value="'.$s_value.'", TestFunction()='.(TestFunction($s_value)?'true':'false');
    $s_value='0xFF';    print "\n".'$s_value="'.$s_value.'", TestFunction()='.(TestFunction($s_value)?'true':'false');
    $s_value='++1';     print "\n".'$s_value="'.$s_value.'", TestFunction()='.(TestFunction($s_value)?'true':'false');
    $s_value='--1';     print "\n".'$s_value="'.$s_value.'", TestFunction()='.(TestFunction($s_value)?'true':'false');
    $s_value='1+';      print "\n".'$s_value="'.$s_value.'", TestFunction()='.(TestFunction($s_value)?'true':'false');
    $s_value='1-';      print "\n".'$s_value="'.$s_value.'", TestFunction()='.(TestFunction($s_value)?'true':'false');
    $s_value='a1';      print "\n".'$s_value="'.$s_value.'", TestFunction()='.(TestFunction($s_value)?'true':'false');
    $s_value='#1';      print "\n".'$s_value="'.$s_value.'", TestFunction()='.(TestFunction($s_value)?'true':'false');
    $s_value='10.e5';   print "\n".'$s_value="'.$s_value.'", TestFunction()='.(TestFunction($s_value)?'true':'false');
    $s_value='0x1';     print "\n".'$s_value="'.$s_value.'", TestFunction()='.(TestFunction($s_value)?'true':'false');
    $s_value='0x';      print "\n".'$s_value="'.$s_value.'", TestFunction()='.(TestFunction($s_value)?'true':'false');
print '</pre>';

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just for arguments sake, shouldn't you be lenient on something like `--1` or `++1`?

Comment: @Jason McCreary, the data is used by something that is not lenient on something like `--1` or `++1`

Comment: Should `.5` be considered valid (as `0.5`)?

Comment: Php's is_numeric function http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Updated with your test data.

```
function TestFunction($s_value) {
    $regex = '/^\s*[+\-]?(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)\s*$/';
    return preg_match($regex, $s_value); 
}

$valid = TestFunction($input);
```

Or trim the input first

```
function TestFunction($s_value) {
    $regex = '/^[+\-]?(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)$/';
    return preg_match($regex, $s_value); 
}

$input = trim($input);
$valid = TestFunction($input);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$decimal = preg_match('/^[+\-]?\d+(\.\d+)?$/', $value) ? (float)$value : 0.0;
```

Comment: That will not match values that contain a single digit, I believe /^[+\-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/ might work

Comment: @rr: It matches single digits fine. I'm not a regex expert, so I plugged it into a file; but as far as I know, the single digit possibility is what the `()?` around the `\.\d+` is for.

Comment: The parentheses were not there when I initially made the comment :)

Comment: I forgot to include this in my sample values, but `.5` does not work with this code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$number = preg_match($number, '/\\A\\s*[+\\-]?\\d*(\\.\\d+)?\\s*\\Z/') ? 
          trim($number) :
          'INVALID';
if ($number === '') { $number = '0'; }
if ($number === 'INVALID') {
    // handle
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about a regular expression? `preg_match(/[+\-]?\d*(\.\d+)?([eE][+\-]?d+)?/,$var);` The `[eE]` bit and after it allows for people to enter 2.3e2 for really big or really small numbers, so leave that out if you don't want it. This whole thing will allow:

```
2
0.3
.3
2.2
+2.2
-2.2
2.3e3
2.3E-3
```

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression would look something like

```
[me@home ~]$ cat test.php
<?php

$regex = "/^([+-]{1})?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$/";

$numbers = array("1", "12345.1", "6789.01", "-1.1", "+1.1", "0", "00001.1");

foreach($numbers as $number) {

        print preg_match($regex, $number)."\n";

}
[me@home ~]$ php -e test.php
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

Comment: I forgot to include this in my sample values, but `.5` does not work with this code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$value = (float)$value;
```