# Validate input is decimal number - input field for currency exchange rate

Tags: php, validation, decimal

I have input field for currency exchange rate.

How do i check, on the server side, that value is not bigger then 2 digits before the decimal point and not more then 2 after?

in sort, the number can be maximum as 99.99

```
<input type="number" name="cc" value="" step=".01" min="0" max="10">
```

Comment: `if($var < 100 && strlen($var) < 5)` ? Why make it harder than that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to validate decimal numbers in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166813/how-to-validate-decimal-numbers-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expression approach in this case:

```
<?php
$rate = $_REQUEST['cc']; //'9.99';
if (preg_match("/^\d{1,2}$|^\d{1,2}\.\d{0,2}$/i", $rate)) {
    echo "A match was found.";
} else {
    echo "A match was not found.";
}
?>
```

[PHP Sandbox code example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d134c58c32088717bf15cf6652dd6007e830f693)

Comment: Thanks Slava, but your code only check the number of digits after the decimal point. I need it to be also maximum 2 digit before the point....can you help me?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Answer fixed and code example linked

Comment: Thank you very much!